# Pattern to solve multiple callbacks in TypeScript

Tags: design-patterns, typescript

I am looking for a way to solve this often occurring problem of mine.

Lets say I have a class as the following in TypeScript:

```
class Example {

    constructor() {
        this.work();
        this.doMoreWork();        
    }

    work() {
        // Work on some more borring async work
    }

    doMoreWork() {
        // Going for some borring async work
    }    

    finishedWorking() {
        // Call me when work() and doMoreWork() is finished
    }
}
```

I would like to call finishedWorking() when work() and doMoreWork() are done. Does anyone know a good pattern I could use in TypeScript to solve this?

As I know async and await is not an option right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I know async and await is not an option right now

Simple answer : yes, not an option

> I would like to call finishedWorking() when work() and doMoreWork() are done

Use Promises!

```
constructor() {
    Promise.all([this.work(),this.doMoreWork()])
           .then(()=>finishedWorking());
}

work() {
    return // some promise //;
}

doMoreWork() {
    return // some promise //;
}
```

Since most user browser's don't support it natively (iojs supports it natively!), you can use something like Q : https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: No async and await is not an option now. Does then() ensure work and doMoreWork runs in parallel?

Comment: No `.then` was series. I've updated my answer to use `Promise.all` to demonstrate how to start these tasks in parallel